# Programatically scroll to the last view in android

Tags: android, scrollview, smooth-scrolling

I want to scroll to the end of the view. Currently i am trying to scroll the scrollview to the end of the latest added view. I tried with setscrolly, smoothscrollto. both works but the problem is both wont scroll to the end, it just scrolls to the last-1 view. Please suggest me how to overcome this.

Comment: did u want to scroll end of page?

Comment: could you provide the could you used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the reason why it was not scrolling to the last view and was stopping at the last-1 view. I was not smoothScrollTo(x,y) in a post thread of the view. Since my scrollview is not refreshed when the last view is added it was not scrolling to the last view.

```
view.post(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
scrollview.smoothScrollTo(x,y);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `transcript mode` param of list view. It provides scrolling to new items automatically:

```
getListView().setTranscriptMode(ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);
```